# Subtracting days from a future date

Tags: php, date, strtotime, date-conversion

```
$tour_date = '11 December 2022';
$newdate = date('j F, Y', strtotime('-10 day', strtotime($tour_date))); 
echo "Make payment until $newdate";
```

It is working as expected. **$newdate** prints as 1 December 2022

However, if the $tour_date is not the current year, it does not work properly. It is still printing as 1 December 2022.

```
$tour_date = '11 December 2023';
$newdate = date('j F, Y', strtotime('-10 day', strtotime($tour_date))); 
echo "Make payment until $newdate";
```

The **$newdate** prints as 1 December 2022. But it should be 1 December 2023 which is -10 days from 11 December 2023.

Any idea, that will work with the current year and also future dates?

**Edit:**

My bad that I did not mention the date is actually like this: $tour_date = '11 December, 2023';

Actually, the app Grammarly removed the comma when I submit the question.

Luckily, @Rylee read my comments and found the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I echo the `$tour_date` and it shows as 11 December, 2023. Do I need to convert before subtracting?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am also confused by this. I have another date which is 2023_12_11. If I can convert to 11-12-2023 it will work. I know because I manually edit in PHPMyAdmin and it worked.

Comment: Yes I converted that date with str_replace, now I can make it work. The problem is nothing works with 11 December 2023, but works with 11-12-2023. I do not know why.

Comment: No. I am sure. Here are metadata: `_date: 11 December, 2023` and  `_metadate: 2023_12_11`
Here are the variables: 
`$tours_date = wc_get_order_item_meta( $key, '_date' );`  and `$tours_date2 = wc_get_order_item_meta( $key, '_metadate' );` Now, $tours_date prints as 11 December, 2023 and $tours_date2 as 2023_12_11. The problem starts after here. `echo date("d F Y", strtotime($tour_date));` prints 11 December 2022. But `echo date("d F Y", strtotime($tour_date2));` prints correct 2023.

Comment: There is a typo in my comment. By $tours_date, I mean $tour_date. So I do not echo the wrong variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that your date is stored as `11 December, 2023`.

The comma `,` is preventing PHP from parsing the date string correctly. Remove the comma (using `str_replace` or similar) and try again.

```php
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-10 day", strtotime("11 December 2023")));  // 2023-12-01
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-10 day", strtotime("11 December, 2023"))); // 2022-12-01
```

In the case with the comma `,` it can't determine the year correctly so it defaults to this year.

After more testing - there seems to be some weird results with that format. I'm not sure why this is exactly:

```php
// Using date("Y-m-d", strtotime($input));
11 December, 1970 -> 1970-12-11
11 December, 1999 -> 1999-12-11
11 December, 2000 -> 2022-12-11
11 December, 2001 -> 2022-12-11
11 December, 2020 -> 2022-12-11
11 December, 2059 -> 2022-12-11
11 December, 2060 -> 2060-12-11
11 December, 2099 -> 2099-12-11
```

It seems that the "year" values after the comma have a special case between 2000 and 2059 (inclusive).

**Further Investigation**

I was intrigued by what was happening in the cases with the comma. As it turns out; PHP is interpreting the part after the comma as a `time` value.

So if that 4 digit number is a valid `time` value, that's how it gets interpreted. You can actually see this if you output the time component of the above examples:

```php
11 December, 1970 -> 1970-12-11 00:00:00
11 December, 1999 -> 1999-12-11 00:00:00
11 December, 2000 -> 2022-12-11 20:00:00
11 December, 2001 -> 2022-12-11 20:01:00
11 December, 2020 -> 2022-12-11 20:20:00
11 December, 2059 -> 2022-12-11 20:59:00
11 December, 2060 -> 2060-12-11 00:00:00
```

Comment: Oh, I was going crazy. Thank you very much. `$newdate = str_replace(',', '', $tour_date);` and then `strtotime('-10 day'` It works!

Comment: @wp-ap not a problem - have a look at the edit, it doesn't seem like an ideal format and I'm not too sure why. More investigation may be required to understand this.

Comment: Thank you once again. The app Grammarly removed the comma when I submit the question. It corrects typo errors. So I did not pay attention. Wow, I learned so much.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the further investigation. So if there is a comma, the year 2000 outputs as 20:00 pm. The year 1970 and 1999 not but for example 1959 will also output as time. (As you said if it is valid time. :-) )

Comment: @wp-ap yep that's right, so any ***time*** value `0000 -> 2459` will be accepted. As you might notice `24:59` is picked up as a time value even though it's not a "valid" time. What actually happens here is that it will increment that day - since the time passes midnight. So `11 December, 2459` ends up being `2022-12-12 00:59:00` (always current year). This is the same for `2400`.

Answer (score 0):

echo 'Make payment until $tour_date (1 December 2022)';

Surely it should echo $newdate?

Comment: $newdate shows 2022, no matter what the $tour_date is.

Comment: @wp-ap  he is saying that in your code, you seem to be echoing $tour_date instead of $new_date

Comment: Sorry, I see. Just typo. Corrected!

Comment: Are your 'j F, Y' formatting options correct?  Could be that the interpreter is wigging out there and defaulting to returning the input as opposed to anything useful.  Meaning you're seeing "(1 December 2022)"

Comment: Remove "(1 December 2022)" from the last section of code and see what you get.

Comment: There is no 1 December 2022. I added it to explain it better. 
It is `echo 'Make payment until $newdate'; `

Answer (score 0):

This:

```php
$tour_date = '11 December 2023';
$newdate = date(
    'j F, Y',
    strtotime(
        '-10 days',
        strtotime($tour_date)
    )
); 
echo "Make payment until $newdate";
```

outputs:

```
Make payment until 1 December, 2023
```

Notice that I replaced `'-10 day'` with `'-10 days'`.
And I used `"` instead of `'` when I used `echo`. Nevertheless, using `'-10 day'` also worked for me… I suspect you made a mistake when you copied the code here. Originally, your code here had:

```php
echo 'Make payment until $tour_date (1 December 2022)';
```

and it was replaced with:

```php
echo 'Make payment until $newdate';
```

You could also have done something like this:

```php
$tour_date = '11 December 2023';
$newdate = date('j F, Y', strtotime("-10 days $tour_date")); 
echo "Make payment until $newdate";
```

Or:

```php
$newdate = (new DateTimeImmutable('11 December 2023'))
    ->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'))
    ->format('j F, Y');
echo "Make payment until $newdate";
```

Comment: They all work on a test.php. (Just a php file) But it prints as 2022 on the thankyou.php woocommerce plugin page. I could not figure it out why.

Comment: When I echo $tour_date, it is 11 December 2023. However this prints as 11 December 2022: `echo date("d F Y", strtotime($tour_date));`
I understand nothing.

Comment: What about this? `echo strtotime($tour_date);`

Comment: Prints this: 1670703780

Comment: I got: 1670716800. `echo date('j F, Y', 1670703780);` outputs: 10 December, 2022. That makes sense. The output depends on the timezone. What about this? `echo strtotime('11 December 2023');`

Answer (score 0):

The code works as expected. Try changing the year on `$tour_date` string

```
$tour_date = '11 December 2022';
```

Comment: $tour_date is woocommerce's product meta data.
`$tour_date = wc_get_order_item_meta( $key, '_date' );`
If I echo $tour_date it is 11 Dec 2023. However this prints as 11 Dec 2022  => `echo date("j F Y", strtotime($tour_date));`

Answer (score -2):

PHP is cursed and nobody should be using it, in my opinion at least.  Either way, here's a working example of that which you intended to achieve:

```
<?php
$originalDate = "2023-12-11";
$daysToSubtract = 10;
$date=date_create($originalDate);
$subtracteddate = date_sub($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string($daysToSubtract . " days")); ###Could be " months", or " seconds"
echo "Original Date: " . date_format($date,"Y-m-d") . "\r\r";
echo "Original minus " . $daysToSubtract . " Days: " . date_format($subtracteddate,"Y-m-d");
?>
```

Comment: PHP is totally fine - weird place to insert an opinion on it.

Comment: Well... I've been doing this for 28 years in a wide variety of languages.  Every time I encounter PHP I cannot shake the sensation that it's somehow "unfinished".  Particularly where the obtuse error messages, or indeed total lack thereof where an error genuinely exists, are concerned.